# Add objects to an array in typescript

Tags: typescript

When a user clicks some items on my web page, I want to store the item details in an array of objects like this:

`[{ "color": "blue", "shape": "square" } , { "color": "red", "shape": "triangle" }]`

However, the following code throws an error when I try to `push(tempObj)`:

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  itemsClicked: {color: string, shape: string}[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): any { }

  onItemClick(color, shape) {
    let tempObj = {};
    tempObj["color"] = color;
    tempObj["shape"] = shape;
    this.itemsClicked.push(tempObj);
  }
}
```

**Error:**

`Argument of type '{}' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ color: string; shape: string; }'.`

Comment: You need to declare the type of `tempObj` to be the same as `{color: string, shape: string}`.

Comment: You have edited the question and now the answer given doesn't fit this. Please don't do that - if you have a new question ask it separately.

Comment: Probably just a question typeo, and probably not causing the error, but `colour` and `color` and not the same spelling for variable names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is not an array of any type, it's an empty array, so you can't push anything to it. Give it an actual type:

```js
itemsClicked: {color: string, shape: string}[]
```

Also make sure you assign it in the constructor.

Comment: How to assign in constructor?

Comment: Either add a constructor like `constructor() { this.itemsClicked = []; }` or let typescript desugar it for you with `itemsClicked: {color: string, shape: string}[] = []`.

Comment: I updated OP with the suggested code, but still getting type error.

Comment: `tempObj` isn't being typed correctly due to first being initialized as `{}`. See [Lazy Object Literal Initialization](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/main-1/lazyobjectliteralinitialization) for fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Also you might encounter an error with `tempObj` like

> Property 'color' does not exist on type '{}'.

Building the whole object directly should fix it

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  itemsClicked: {color: string, shape: string}[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): any { }
  onItemClick(color: string, shape: string) {
    this.itemsClicked.push({ color, shape }); // <--
  }
}
```